# Xcode Cloud Build Error : "Unable to open target file"

Tags: ios, swift, github, xcode-cloud

I have tried to implement Xcode Cloud. Getting this error while generating the build.
Tried solution:
Pod deintegrate and pod install again. But it's not resolved. Please suggest me a solution for this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this error by following the steps given in apple doc [AppleDoc- Custom scripts](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/writing-custom-build-scripts),